# How to Update end date by adding duration to start date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

As in title i don't know how to add duration (from the same table) to start date, to get end date in result, table is looks like:

```
create table NR1
(
  id         INTEGER not null,
  price      INTEGER,
  price2     INTEGER,
  start_date DATE,
  end_date   DATE,
  duration   NUMBER
)
```

i tried something like this, but i have some errors:

```
update nr1
set end_date =dateadd(MONTH, nr1.duration, nr1.start_date);
```

it should works, but i have problems with `MONTH`, at all SQL developer says that.

Comment: What are those 'some errors', please?

Comment: @vahdet it's "uncorrect identificator"

Comment: Where [in the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `dateadd()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [`add_months`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543):

```
update NR1
set end_date = add_months(start_date, duration)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using syntax form a different database platform. The Oracle equivalent is [the `add_months()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ADD_MONTHS.html#GUID-B8C74443-DF32-4B7C-857F-28D557381543):

```
update nr1
set end_date = add_months(nr1.start_date, nr1.duration);
```

If you just [add a plain number to a date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF-GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) that's treated as a number of (whole or partial) days. You can also use intervals (via [`numtodsinterval()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NUMTODSINTERVAL.html)) for other periods of time, but using that for months can be difficult.

Months and days are simple through the basic functionality and functions though.

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you should consider using a virtual column so you don't have to maintain both values.

Answer (score -3):

These are perfectly working SQL statement.

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 5, '5:00');
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, '5:00');
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 5, '5:00');
```

You can try queries here: [W3Schools Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_dateadd)

Comment: None of those are valid in Oracle.